# <style> doesn't apply and I'm not sure why

Tags: html, css

I have a bit of very basic HTML and was trying to style a `div` with an inline style. The first snippet one works by putting the style in the `head` element, but the other snippet doesn't work at all.  What is the reasoning?

**Works**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #click-me {
            background-color: red;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='click-me'></div>
    <iframe src='//someURL' width=800 height=600>
</body>
</html>
```

**Doesn't work**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div id='click-me'></div>
    <iframe src='//someURL' width=800 height=600>


    <style>
        #click-me {
            background-color: red;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why don't you just use the css file like it should? Yes, there are situations where it might be handy to add inline css, but I can't see why here?

Comment: It's purely an example.  Just wanted to know why it was failing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `<style>` tag is inside the `<iframe>` tag, and is therefore not parsed as part of the parent document.

Add `</iframe>` and it should work.

Comment: Yes, the unclosed `iframe` is probably the reason why it doesn't work, but the `style` tag shouldn't be in the body in the first place.

Comment: Ha, well spotted! +1

Comment: Very nice answer!  Completely groked that... Many thanks!  I'll accept in 6 mins b/c it will not allow me right now.

Answer (score 7):

The `style` element is designed to only be placed within in your HTML document's `head` element (where metadata is expected).

If you want to use an *inline style*, you'd do this instead:

```
<div id='click-me' style='background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 200px;'></div>
```

However this is usually frowned upon as styling should be contained within a stylesheet for ease of maintenance.

**Edit:** The reason this doesn't work in your case is covered in SLaks' answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26258094/1317805

Comment: Anyway HTML5 introduced _scoped style_: http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/ Some browser applies that style when defined inside the element itself

Comment: Actually, `<style>` works anywhere.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan this only works on Firefox though. http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped

Comment: @SLaks You are right in that one, but it is supposed to be placed inside the header ;)

Comment: @SLaks I never said it didn't, I just said that it's intended to be placed within the `head` element.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pajwl is not scoped but this works on Chrome and the style is not in the head